# Sync issue from Muvizu image sequence to Blender

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

My idea is to make an short animation overlaid on a choir video as seen on the pic below.

In that regard;

1. I imported and opened the Choir video (the basic one) on Blender Video Editing window.
2. I made a small video on Muvizu which is 25 Fps and exported it through layers (png files).
3. I then imported  the Muvizu image sequence on Blender Video Editing window.
4. The choir video is 30 fps but Muvizu is 25 fps.

[image]

**Issue:**

Once the video is played on the Video editing window, the Choir video hangs around 30 fps, which is fine. As soon as it gets to the first layer of the imported Png sequence (from Muzivu), the fps fall  down to around 7-10 on average.
I then selected the Muvizu image sequence and tried to create a proxy (Strip Proxy & Timecode) with a 25% resolution on this Muvizu strip.
BUT... when I hit "Rebuild Proxy and Timecode Indices" button, it does not create the BL Proxy folder where it should be. it does not seem to do the job. It does not seem to build any and my output location is properly selected for it.

So, I do not know if all this has anything to do with the "Not proxy folder being built" or not but the end result is that:
a) My muvizu video is perfectly sync on Muvizu
b) but not on Blender where I need to render the final animation.
It is slower on Blender software.

Any idea of what is going on here? What am I doing wrong?

Do not hesitate to ask me more details if needed.

Thanks in advance. Roland

*Note: shall I had that once I imported the Muvizu image sequence, I had to use Reverse function since they had been all reversed once imported!*

Comment: You'll need to ensure all source material have the same FPS and they matches the render FPS. The vse do not support multiple FPS. Any GUI for ffmpeg can be used to change the FPS.

Comment: I will see what I can do this way. THanks TinTwotin